# EmojiModule not found and could not use EmojiService in my component. Angular 7.1.0 and TypeScript 3.1.6

Tags: angular, typescript, emoji, angular7

I am using ngx-emoji-mart in my angular chat application. I am using Angular 7.1.0 and TypeScript 3.1.6.

EmojiModule could not be resolved in my Chat Module. I cannot import it. Angular gives EmojiModule not resolved. Other than this, I could not use EmojiService in my component.

I am importing EmojiService in my component like this:
constructor(public emoji: EmojiService) {}

Component HTML:

`<emoji-mart (emojiClick)="addEmoji($event)" class='emoji-mart'></emoji-mart>`

TS:

`//addEmoji function
addEmoji(event){ const styles = this.emoji.emojiSpriteStyles($event.emoji.sheet, 'twitter'); // pass emoji sheet }`

I cannot use `this.emoji.emojiSpriteStyles()`
I have searched a lot around ngx-emoji-mart github issues and stackoverflow but nothing worked for me. Thanks

Comment: "EmojiModule could not be resolved in my Chat Module. I cannot import it. " Show code for this.

Comment: I am importing Emoji Module like this: 
`import { EmojiModule } from '@ctrl/ngx-emoji-mart/ngx-emoji/public_api';`

and in my ngModule:
`imports     : [
        PickerModule,
        EmojiModule
    ]`

Comment: try this `import { EmojiService, CompressedEmojiData, emojis, EmojiModule } from '@ctrl/ngx-emoji-mart/ngx-emoji';`